# Response Event listener for a specific action

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have an event listener, with a method looking like this

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event,EntityManager $entityManager)
{

    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
    }



    if ($controller[0] instanceof UserController) {

        //@TODO limit this for Controller action editUser() only

        $response = $event->getResponse()->getContent();
        $responseDecoded = json_decode($response);
        if ($responseDecoded instanceof UserProperties) {

        }
    }


}
```

my services.yml looks like this

```
update_user_controller_listener_marking_tasks:
        class: Company\UserResultBundle\EventListener\UserEditListener
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

the problem is the listener runs for every action executed in that user controller, which i do not want.

My question is how I can limit to be running at the response of a specific action only. Let us say `editUser()` ?

I was not able to find this explicitly shown the documentation

Comment: If the code you need to run is specific to a particular method on a particular controller why wouldn't you just put it in that controller method rather than an event?

Comment: I just did not want to get the controller too messy with calls to other services.

Comment: If you use events to de-couple something that shouldn't really be decoupled it tends to obfuscate the code unnecessarily. Which services are you planning to call from the event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the event dispacher component to create your own event, and dispatch it in the actions you want. Info here: [The EventDispatcher Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can check `$controller[1]` value - it contains controller's action method name:

```
if ($controller[0] instanceof UserController) {

    // limit this for Controller action editUser() only
    if ($controller[1] === 'editUserAction') {

         ...
```

Answer (score 2):

How about throw a custom Exception and do this:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    // You get the exception object from the received event
    $exception = $event->getException();
    if('Some\Namespace\ApiException' == get_class($exception)){
        $res = new JsonResponse([
            'message'=>$exception->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
        $event->setResponse($res);
    }
}
```